# About integrals w.r.t. the counting measure

Tags: measure-theory

Consider the measure space $(\mathbb{Z},\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z}),\#)$, where $\#$ is the counting measure on $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z})$ is its power set.

I would like to show that for any measurable function we have $\int f(n)d\#(n)=\sum_{n}f(n)$.

This is what I have done: Let $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ and consider the indicator function $1_{\{x\}}$. Then $$\int_\mathbb{Z} fd\#=\int_\mathbb{Z} 1_{\{x\}}d\#=\#\{x\}=1,$$ for $f=1_{\{x\}}$. Next, for a step function $f=\sum_{k=-n}^na_k1_{\{x_k\}}$ (where $x_k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $a_k$ are real rumbers for all $k$) we have $$\int_\mathbb{Z} fd\#=\sum_{k=-n}^na_k\int_\mathbb{Z}1_{\{x\}}d\#=\sum_{k=-n}^na_k.$$

How do I finish this proof? I still need to prove the statement for an arbitrarily measurable function.

Comment: How did you define the Lebesgue integral?

Comment: And how did you define infinite sums over $\mathbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 4):

I think the statement holds only for positive measurable functions. If you take $ f(n) = \frac{(-1)^n}{n} $ then $ \sum_n f(n) < \infty $ but $$ \int_\mathbb{Z} f^+ d\# = \int_\mathbb{Z} f^- d\# = \infty $$ So you end up with $\infty-\infty $

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $f$ be a measurable function, $f \geq 0$. Then there exists a sequence $(f_n)_n$ of step functions such that $f = \sup_n f_n$. Now apply [monotone convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Lebesgue.27s_monotone_convergence_theorem) and use the formula for the step functions (which you already proved).

If $f$ is an arbritary measurable function you can write $f$ as $f=f^+-f^-$ where $f^+$, $f^- \geq 0$ are measurable functions.